# How can I create a reusable function to enforce "unique_together" in Django 1.8 with multiple null values?

Tags: python, django, rest

I am using django 1.8, and REST 3.0 with an angular frontend.

I had set unique_together on the meta class for two fields on my model.
It did not work well because it would not allow for multiple cases where field1 and field2 were null. 
I need these fields to be both optional
or if one has a value then the other must have a value as well.
Together, they should be unique (unique_together)

What I have so far is ridiculous and ugly. I do not know how to write it any better or more efficiently, but would love to learn how to do this in a more Pythonic way.

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
#field1 and field2 are nested in an array that is only POSTed if it exists. 

if 'key' in 'data':
    field1 = data[key].get(field1,"")
    field2 = data[key].get(field2,"")

elif 'key' not in 'data':
   field1 = "" 
   field2 = ""

if field1=="" and field2=="":
   field1 = None
   field2 = None

elif (field1 == "") and (field2 != ""):
   data.errors += 'You added field 2 but did not add field 1.'

elif (field1 !="") and (field2 ==""):
   data.errors += 'You added field 1 but did not add field 2.'

elif (field1 = "") and (country_code!=""):
   try:
       field1Db = [model].objects.get(field1=field1)
   except [model].DoesNotExist:
       valid_field1 = True
   else:
       if field1Db and ((field1Db.field2)) == (field2):
       data.errors += Field 1 + 'and' + Field 2 + 'should form a unique set if both are submitted.'
else:
   data.errors = False
   data.success = True
   return Response(data)
```

It seems to work, just ugly.

After this, I send data to a serializer.
Anyway, If anyone knows how to do this more effectively, I would really be appreciative to learn how. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `unique_together` to validate the case when both values are provided. Then add a `clean` method to your model that makes sure that either both values are provided, or neither is.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ... 
    def clean(self):
        """
        Make sure that if field1 or field2 is specified, 
        then they are both specified.
        """
        if self.field1 is not None and self.field2 is None:
            raise ValidationError('you must specify field2 if you specify field1')
        elif self.field1 is None and self.field2 is not None:
            raise ValidationError('you must specify field1 if you specify field2')
```

Comment: wow...that is like a million times better looking. Thank you @Alasdair!